# What's the most efficient way to copy and paste brackets and their contents in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm aware of how to copy the text within a set of brackets with the following command:

```
yi[
```

So when I use this command while my cursor is on the following line:

```
[:test, :array]
```

I can use **p** to paste `:test, :array`

What I want to do though is paste `[:test, :array]`.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command which you wanted

```
ya[
```

Comment: Nice!  Been using vim for years and never knew this one.  Works on nested brackets too.  Is there something similar for copying/cutting an entire C function cleanly and correctly?

Comment: Paragraph (`yap`) or block (`ya{`) selection is the closest I know of.

Comment: Type  `:help object-select` this will give you an idea of what type of objects you can select/delete/change @wossname